# How to read controle signals from the opcode for a single-clock processor

Tags: assembly, mips

At the moment I am wondering how I can read the settings for a control unit in a single-cycle processor from an opcode. Is there a logical way behind it or is there another way to solve the problem? The opcode I need results from Mips Assembler.
A picture of the processor is attached. [singe-clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCshw.png)

For example. If I have an Add instruction, the opcode in mips is 000000 but the control unit returns RegDst 1; Branch 0; MemRead 0; MemtoReg 0; ALUOP 10; MemWrite 0; MemRead 0; RegWrite 1. I understand why the control unit is doing that, but I can't see the connection between this and the opcode.

Comment: There's a circuit called the *instruction decoder* that translates the instruction into control signals.  It can be very complex, depending on how complex the instruction encoding of your CPU is.

Comment: @fuz: MIPS is designed to make decoding as easy as possible.  For example, all(?) R-type instructions have opcode `000000`, with a separate `funct` field that's sent to the ALU control input.  (And also decoded by other parts of the CPU to detect `jr` and `jalr`, which are R-type with opcode=0, so the register value has to get muxed to the new PC)  https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~isg/res/mips/opcodes has a table.  (I think their "Opcode/Function" is showing just the funct field for R-type instructions where the opcode is 0, otherwise the opcode field.  Other than that, seems pretty good.)

Comment: But yes, the control unit has to map the 6-bit opcode field to a set of output signals as fuz said.  MIPS achieves simplicity by making those signals depend only on 6 bits of the instruction word, and probably some patterns in the choice of opcodes makes the amount of logic simpler than the worst case of an arbitrary 6-input truth table for each output.

Comment: I don't see how that single-cycle MIPS can execute `jr $ra` or other indirect jumps.  The muxing into PC doesn't include a way to get a register-file output into it.  (The ALU's "zero" output is for instructions like `beq`, where that flag result feeds into the muxer.)  Perhaps this is a super-simplified MIPS without the ability to do indirect jumps like returning from functions.